# Finding every $n$ such that $a_n$ is an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let us define $\{a_n\}$ as $a_1=a_2=1$,$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+\frac{a_n}{2}\ \ (n=1,2,\cdots).$$
Then, is the following conjecture true?

> **A conjecture** : If $a_n$ is an integer, then $n\le 8$.

I conjectured this by using computer, but I don't have any good idea to prove it. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's a linear recurrence relation. You can find an analytic expression for $a_n$. Did you try that?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Of course yes.

Comment: If I did not make calculation mistake;

$$a_n=c_1(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2})^n+c_2(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2})^n$$ where $c_1=\dfrac{3-\sqrt 3}{6} $ and $c_2=1-c_1$

Comment: See also [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%2B2%29%3Da%28n%2B1%29%2Ba%28n%29%2F2%2C+a%280%29%3D0%2C+a%281%29%3D1).

Comment: @lhf: I wasted my three minutes :)

Comment: @NicoDean, same thing, solving for $a(0)$. It's just that WA gives a better formula for the initial conditions $a(0)=0, a(1)=1$.

Comment: @NicoDean: it is not so important, just put $n+1$ instead of $n$ the you will get it.

Comment: I tried a quick script on my computer, and I get that $a_{111}=627138555568356$. Maybe there's some numerical error, though.

Comment: @Bhoot: you mean $a_{111}$ ?

Comment: @Bhoot, it's a numerical error: $a_{111}=627138555568356.22\dots$.

Comment: i also nan on c++ to get very large numbers

Comment: @mathlove: By the way,Did you see this problem anywhere or you made up it for  fun  ?

Comment: @aditya have you not created a class to do operations on arbitrary large numbers ;)?

Comment: @mesel: I made up it just for fun. It surprised me a lot:)

Comment: @mathlove: interesting question, hope to see the solution :)

Comment: It seems that $a_{2k+1}$ needs $k$ decimal digits for $k\ge 1$. This may be provable by induction.

Comment: $((1-\sqrt3)/2)^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, so, @Nico, your formula gives negative numbers for all $n$ from some point on. Seems unlikely.

Comment: My formular above is missing a minus-sign infront. Here the correct and simplified formular: $$a_n=\frac{2^{-n}}{\sqrt{3}} \Big((\sqrt{3} + 1)^n - (\sqrt{3} - 1)^n e^{i n \pi}\Big)$$

Comment: What's $a_{16}$? $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_4$ and $a_8$ worked...

Comment: @jonnytan999: Sorry: 679/8

Comment: $2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_n$ is well known: http://oeis.org/A048788.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought I'd write up some observations that I think are essentially a proof, but it could stand to be vetted and better presented.  I'll try to come back and do this myself, but I'd be happy if someone else sees a nice way to clean things up and does so in a separate answer.  (If you do, please tack on comment on to this answer, so I can put an edit here redirecting readers.)

Starting with the OEIS sequence $1,2,3,8,11,30,41,112,\ldots$ in lhf's answer, which lhf noted consists of alternating odd and even terms, extract the even terms to get the [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A052530)

$$0, 2, 8, 30, 112, 418, 1560, 5822, 21728, 81090, 302632, 1129438, 4215120, 15731042,\ldots$$

which satisfies the two-term recursion $a(n+1)=4a(n)-a(n-1)$.  (Note the addition of $0$ at the beginning.  This turns out to be fairly important.)  If we factor out a $2$, this *again* alternates between even and odd:

$$0, 1, 4, 15, 56, 209, 780, 2911, 10864, 40545, 151316, 564719, 2107560, 7865521,\ldots$$

so tossing aside the odd terms gives

$$0,4,56,780,10864,151316,2107560,\ldots$$

Now it's easy to show that anytime you pick out every other term of a sequence with a two-term recursion, the new sequence still satisfies a two-term recursion:  If $a(n+1)=\alpha a(n)+\beta a(n-1)$, then $a(2n+2)=(\alpha^2+2\beta)a(2n)-\beta^2a(2n-2)$.  Since our $\beta$ is $-1$, this new sequence satisfies the recursion $a(n+1)=14a(n)-a(n-1)$, where $14=4^2-2$.  This time we can factor a $4$ out of the sequence, leaving

$$0,1,14,195,2716,37829,526890,\ldots$$

which again alternates odd and even terms, for the simple reason that the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for its two-term recursion are also even and odd, just as $4$ and $-1$ were in the sequence it came from.  So we *repeat*:

$$0,14,2716,526890,\ldots$$

Factoring out the $14$ makes this

$$0,1,194,37635,\ldots$$

which satisfies the two-term recursion $a(n+1)=194a(n)-a(n-1)$, where $194=14^2-2=(4^2-2)^2-2$.  It's becoming clear what's happening:  At the $m$th step, we wind up with a sequence of the form

$$0,1,r_m,r_m^2-1,r_m^3-2r_m,\ldots$$

which satisfies the recursion $a(n+1)=r_ma(n)-a(n-1)$, with $r_m=r_{m-1}^2-2$.  In particular, the sequence of $r_m$'s is $4,14,194,\ldots$, so that after the first $4$, all the terms are $2$ times an odd number.  So when you pass to the next batch of even terms,

$$0,r_m,r_m^3-2r_m,\ldots$$

and then factor out the $r_m$ to get the next sequence $0,1,r_{m+1},r_{m+1}^2-1,\ldots$, you are taking out only one power of $2$.  If you think carefully about what all this means, I think it explains the serrations in lhf's graph and shows that you wind up with large powers of $2$ in the denominator of the OP's original sequence after the eighth term, as conjectured.

Comment: So, I think you want to say the followings : if $n=2^p(2k-1)$ for $p=0,1$, then $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}a_n=2^p(2m-1)$. If $n=2^p(2k-1)$ for $p\ge 2$, then $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}a_n=2^{p+1}(2m-1)$. It's very easy to see that these do prove my conjecture. Thank you!

Comment: @mathlove, I couldn't have said it better myself.  To paraphrase Pascal, I would have written a shorter proof, but I didn't have the time....

Answer (score 9):

Let us write $a_n = \frac{p_n}{q_n}$, where $\gcd(p_n,q_n)=1$. Then we have from the recurrence relation that
$$\frac{p_{n+2}}{q_{n+2}} = \frac{2q_n p_{n+1} + p_n q_{n+1}}{2q_nq_{n+1}}$$
with $p_1=q_1=p_2=q_2=1$. In particular we see that for each $n$ we can write $q_n = 2^{j_n}$ for some $j_n \ge 0$.

From numerical evidence we guess the following formulas for $j_n$:

- $j_{2k+1} = k$, where $k \ge 0$
- $j_{2(2k+1)} = 2k$, where $k \ge 0$
- $j_4 = 0$
- $j_{2^u(2k+1)} = 2^{u-1} (2k + 1) - u - 1$, where $u \ge 2$, $k \ge 0$, $2^u(2k+1) \neq 4$

Notice that $j_n = 0$ only for $n=1,2,4,8$. These are the only values for which $a_n$ is an integer.

To prove all this, we define the sequence $p_n$ by the recurrence relation
$$p_n = 2^{j_n - j_{n-1}} p_{n-1} + 2^{j_n - j_{n-2} - 1} p_{n-2}, p_1 = p_2 = 1.$$
We have to show that $p_n$ is an odd integer for all $n \neq 4$ ($p_4 = 2$). This can be done by induction.

Here are sketches for the induction steps:

**Case 1a**: $n-1$ is of the form $2(2k+1)$

In this case we have $p_n = 2 p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}$, we are done by induction.

**Case 1b**: $n-1$ is of the form $2^u(2k+1)$

In this case we have $p_n = 2^{u+1} p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}$, we are done by induction.

**Case 2a**: $n$ is of the form $2(2k+1)$

In this case we have $p_n = p_{n-1} + 2^u p_{n-2}$, we are done by induction.

**Case 2b**: $n$ is of the form $2^u(2k+1)$

In this case we have $p_n = \frac{p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}}{2^u}$. We have to show that the largest power of $2$ that divides $p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}$ is $2^u$.

To do this consider the sequence $r_n = p_{4n-1} + p_{4n-2}$. By using the defining relation of $p_n$, one can show that $r_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation $r_n = 14 r_{n-1} - r_{n-2}$ with $r_1 = 4$, $r_2 = 56$. Once we have shown that $r_{2^u(2k+1)}$ is divisible by $2^{u+2}$, we are done.

We can as well consider the sequence $s_n = r_n/4$, defined by the same recurrence relation with initial values $s_1 = 1$, $s_2 = 14$. This is [A007655](http://oeis.org/A007655) in OEIS. We have the generating function
$$S(x) = \frac{x}{1 - 14x + x^2}.$$
To extract the coefficients of $x^{2^u(2k+1)}$, where $u$ is fixed, we define the sequence of generating functions
$$S_n(x) = \frac{S_{n-1}(\sqrt{x}) + S_{n-1}(-\sqrt{x})}{2}, \quad S_1(x) = S(x).$$
By induction we see that
$$S_n(x) = \frac{A(1) \dots A(n-1) x}{1 - A(n) x + x^2}$$
where $A(1) = 14$, $A(n+1) = A(n)^2 - 2$. Indeed,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
S_n(x) & = & \frac{\frac{A(1) \dots A(n-2) \sqrt{x}}{1 - A(n-1) \sqrt{x} + x} - \frac{A(1) \dots A(n-2) \sqrt{x}}{1 + A(n-1) \sqrt{x} + x}}{2} \\
& = & \frac{A(1) \dots A(n-2) A(n-1) x}{(1 + x)^2 - A(n-1)^2 x} \\
& = & \frac{A(1) \dots A(n-1) x}{1 - (A(n-1)^2 - 2) x + x^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now $R_u(x) = \frac{S_{u+1}(\sqrt{x}) - S_{u+1}(-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$ corresponds to the generating function of the terms $r_{2^u(2k + 1)}$, where $u$ is fixed. We have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{S_u(\sqrt{x}) - S_u(-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} & = & \frac{\frac{A(1) \dots A(u-1) \sqrt{x}}{1 - A(u-1) \sqrt{x} + x} + \frac{A(1) \dots A(u-1) \sqrt{x}}{1 + A(u-1) \sqrt{x} + x}}{2\sqrt{x}} \\
& = & \frac{A(1) \dots A(u-1) \sqrt{x}(1 + x)}{\sqrt{x}(1 - A(u) x + x^2)} \\
& = & \frac{A(1) \dots A(u-1) (1 + x)}{1 - A(u) x + x^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Clearly by definition each $A(k)$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$. Therefore the product $A(1) \dots A(u-1) A(u)$ in front of $R(u)$ has exactly $u$ factors of $2$. Because $A(u)$ is even, the coefficients of the taylor series of $\frac{1}{1 - A(u) x + x^2}$ alternate between even and odd. Therefore $\frac{1+x}{1 - A(u) x + x^2}$ has odd coefficients. This proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer. I'm trying to understand the answer now. One thing. Maybe you want to write $j_{2^u(2k+1)}=2^{u−1}(2k+1)−u−1$, where $u\ge 2,k\ge 0,(u,k)\not =(2,0)$, right? Also, when you have four cases, I think $p_4$ may need to be considered separately because it is even. This must be a tiny point, but I'm confused a bit.

Comment: @mathlove: Thanks for the catch: $u$ should definitely be $\ge 2$ there. And yes, strictly speaking $p_4$ should be done separately, but it's easy to see that everything works. I was implicitly assuming that we start the induction from a bit larger index, since the first few $p_n$ can be checked by hand.

Answer (score 2):

*Partial answer. Work in progress.*

Let $b_n= 2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_n$. This sequence is well known: [oeis.org/A048788](http://oeis.org/A048788):
$$
1, 2, 3, 8, 11, 30, 41, 112, 153, 418, 571, 1560, 2131, 5822, \dots
$$

It satisfies
$$
b_{2n} = 2b_{2n-1} + b_{2n-2}
$$
$$
b_{2n+1} = b_{2n} + b_{2n-1}
$$

It is clear from these equations and the initial conditions that $b_n \bmod 2$ is $1,0,1,0,1,\dots$. In particular, $b_n$ is odd for $n$ odd. This implies that $a_n$ is not an integer for $n$ odd.

My original strategy, which lead to the approach above, is to consider the number of decimal places required to represent $a_n$. Empirically, it follows $n/2$, as the argument above shows, but for some $n$. notably powers of $2$, the number of decimal places goes down noticeably. See the picture below. The approach above shows that $n/2$ suffice but I need a *lower* bound, not an upper bound.

[image]

Comment: Additionally, another induction proof shows that $b_n$ and $b_{n+1}$ are coprime for all $n$. (By the first part, we only need consider odd common divisors.) That is as far as I got. It does seem that the $b_{2n}$ will be divisible by progressively larger powers of $2$ as $n$ grows, so we still need a good way to bound these powers. (Now abandoning my own answer, which amounted to your answer plus these observations.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen. OEIS says that the sequence is "a strong divisibility sequence, that is, $\gcd(b(n),b(m)) = b(\gcd(n,m))$.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. That is how I got turned onto the same train of thought that you are pursuing here. But there is no reference for this claim, and I can't immediately see why it is true. So I am wary of relying on it.

Comment: The even terms, $2,8,30,112,ldots$, are isolated in the OEIS sequence http://oeis.org/A052530 with the recursion $a(n)=4a(n-1)-a(n-2)$.  Not that that seems to help much....